# How to test a custom event by passing a manipulated event object

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test the `changeDate` event of my [bootstrap datepicker](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/#):

```
elem.on('changeDate', function(event) {
    var newVal = event.date;
    ...
});
```

with Jasmine:

```
it('sets a new startDate', function() {
    elem.trigger('changeDate', {date: new Date(2014, 1, 2)});
    expect(elem.datepicker('getDate')).toEqual(new Date(2014, 1, 2));
});
```

When logging `event`, the whole datepicker `object` is returned but `date` is still `undefined`. How should I pass my custom test `date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
it('sets a new startDate', function() {
    var event = jQuery.Event('changeDate');
    event.date = new Date(2014, 1, 2);
    elem.trigger(event);
    expect(elem.datepicker('getDate')).toEqual(new Date(2014, 1, 2));
});
```

does the trick.